# Deserialize XML fails to connect class to elements

Tags: windows-phone-7, serialization, xmlreader

I'm trying to deserialize an XML document from the web into associated classes for a Windows Phone 7 environment. I've used an async to grab the document, it loads into an XmlReader as far as I can tell with the debugger, and a deserializer reports it can be deserialized. When I try to deserialize I get an empty class.

This is the class I want to populate from the Xml:

```
namespace CineQuest
{
    //[Serializable()]
    //This is the main head of the XML data object
    [XmlRoot("festival")]
    public class Festival
    {
    /* Later */
    //[XmlElement("program_items")]
    //public ProgramItems programItems  { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("films")]
    public Films films { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("schedules")]
    public Schedules schedules { get; set; }

    /* Later */
    //[XmlElement("venue_Locations")]
    //public VenueLocations venueLocations { get; set; }
}

public class Films
{
    [XmlArray("films")]
    [XmlArrayItem("film", typeof(Film))]
    public List<Film> filmsList { get; set; }

    public Films()
    {
        filmsList = new List<Film>();
    }
}

public class Film
{
    [XmlElementAttribute("id")]
    public string id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("title")]
    public string title { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("description")]
    public string description { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("tagline")]
    public string tagline { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("genre")]
    public string genre { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("imageURL")]
    public string imageURL { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("director")]
    public string director { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("producer")]
    public string producer { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("cinematographer")]
    public string cinematographer { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("editor")]
    public string editor { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("cast")]
    public string cast { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("country")]
    public string country { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("language")]
    public string language { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("film_info")]
    public string film_info { get; set; }
}

public class Schedules
{
    [XmlArray("schedules")]
    [XmlArrayItem("schedule", typeof(Schedule))]
    public List<Schedule> schedulesList { get; set; }

    public Schedules()
    {
        schedulesList = new List<Schedule>();
    }
}

public class Schedule
{
    [XmlElementAttribute("id")]
    public string id { get; set; }

    [XmlElementAttribute("program_item_id")]
    public string programItemId { get; set; }

    [XmlElementAttribute("start_time")]
    public string startTime { get; set; }

    [XmlElementAttribute("end_time")]
    public string endTime { get; set; }

    [XmlElementAttribute("venue")]
    public string venue { get; set; }
}
}
```

And this is how I'm trying to do it:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Festival));
reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(data.Result));
object deserialization = serializer.Deserialize(reader);
MessageBox.Show(deserialization.ToString());
festival = (Festival)deserialization;

FilmItemList list = new FilmItemList(festival);
list.populateList();         
foreach (FilmItem item in list.Itemlist)
{
    this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = item.lineone, LineTwo =    item.linetwo, LineThree = item.linethree, LineFour = item.linefour });
}
```

I know I can populate the classes as I've done it manually, but I know I'm missing something to connect the Xml being deserialized to the classes they're supposed to connect to, but I have no idea what.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to decorate all of your classes with the `Serializable` attribute, if they are to be serialized.